# Python AST module can not detect "if" or "for"

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to restrict a user-provided script, with the following visitor:

```
class SyntaxChecker(ast.NodeVisitor):

    def check(self, syntax):
        tree = ast.parse(syntax)
        print(ast.dump(tree), syntax)
        self.visit(tree)

    def visit_Call(self, node):
        print('Called for Call', ast.dump(node))
        if isinstance(node.func, ast.Call) and node.func.id not in allowed_functions:
            raise CodeError("%s is not an allowed function!"%node.func.id)
        elif isinstance(node.func, ast.Attribute) and node.func.value.id not in allowed_classes:
            raise CodeError('{0} is not calling an allowed class'.format(node.func.value.id))
        elif isinstance(node.func, ast.Name) and node.func.id in allowed_classes:
            raise CodeError('You are not allowed to instantiate any class, {0}'.format(node.func.id))
        else:
            ast.NodeVisitor.generic_visit(self, node)

    def visit_Assign(self, node):
        print('Called for Assign', ast.dump(node))
        ast.NodeVisitor.generic_visit(self, node)

    def visit_Attribute(self, node):
        print('Called for Attribute', ast.dump(node))
        if node.value.id not in allowed_classes:
            raise CodeError('"{0}" is not an allowed class'.format(node.value.id))
        elif node.value.id in allowed_classes and isinstance(node.ctx, ast.Store):
            raise CodeError('Trying to change something in a pre-defined class, "{0}" in "{1}"'.format(node.attr, node.value.id))
        else:
            ast.NodeVisitor.generic_visit(self, node)

    def visit_Expr(self, node):
        print('Called for Expr', ast.dump(node))
        ast.NodeVisitor.generic_visit(self, node)

    def visit_Name(self, node):
        print('Called for Name', ast.dump(node))
        if isinstance(node.ctx, ast.Store) and node.id in allowed_classes:
            raise CodeError('Trying to change a pre-defined class, {0}'.format(node.id))
        elif isinstance(node.ctx, ast.Load) and node.id not in safe_names and node.id not in allowed_functions and node.id not in allowed_classes:
            raise CodeError('"{0}" function is not allowed'.format(node.id))
        else:
            ast.NodeVisitor.generic_visit(self, node)

    def generic_visit(self, node):
        print('Called for generic', ast.dump(node))        
        if type(node).__name__ not in allowed_node_types:
            raise CodeError("%s is not allowed!"%type(node).__name__)
        else:
            ast.NodeVisitor.generic_visit(self, node)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Check whole file
    x = SyntaxChecker()
    code = open(sys.argv[1], 'r').read()
    try:
        x.check(code)
    except CodeError as e:
        print(repr(e))

    # Or check line by line, considering multiline statements
    code = ''
    for line in open(sys.argv[1], 'r'):
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            code += line
            try:
                print('[{0}]'.format(code))
                x.check(code)
                code = ''
            except CodeError as e:
                print(repr(e))
                break
            except SyntaxError as e:
                print('********Feeding next line', repr(e))
```

It is doing fine for the time being, and I will tune it more but the problem is that this always throws `SyntaxError('unexpected EOF while parsing', ('<unknown>', 1, 15, 'for j in A.b():'))` while parsing something like this

```
for j in A.b():
    print('hey')
```

and because of this, no `for` or `if` gets parsed.

EDIT: I have added code to check for whole code at once, or check multi-line statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are parsing the code line by line, but a `for` loop *does not stand alone*. A `for` loop without a suite is a syntax error. Python expected to find a suite and found the EOF (end of file) instead.

In other words, your parser can only handle [Simple Statements](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html) and standalone [Expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html) on one physical line, and [Compound Statements](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html) if they are directly followed by a Simple Statement or Expression on the same line.

Your code will also fail for:

- Multiline strings

  ```
  somestring = """Containing more
  than one
  line"""
  ```
- Line continuations

  ```
  if the_line == 'too long' and \
     a_backslash_was_used in (True, 'true'):
      # your code fails

  somevar = (you_are_allowed_to_use_newlines,
      "inside parentheses and brackets and braces")
  ```

Using `ast.parse()` to check code line by line is not going to work here; it is only suitable for whole suites; on a file by file basis I'd only pass in the *whole file*.

To check code line by line you need to tokenize it yourself. You can use the [`tokenize` library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tokenize.html); it'll report either a `SyntaxError` exception or a `tokenize.TokenError` on syntax errors.

if you wanted to restrict a script, take a look at [`asteval`](https://github.com/newville/asteval); either the project itself or its source code. They parse *the whole script*, then execute based on the resulting AST nodes (limiting what nodes they'll accept).

Comment: So what should I for `if` or `for`? Manually parse them?

Comment: @thelastblack: you need to feed multiple lines, at the very least. Take into account that a suite can contain empty lines, so feeding until there is no error is not enough.

Comment: Now you're saying I have to invent the wheel? Isn't it invented before? I will try feeding until there is not error to see the results

Comment: @thelastblack: take a look at the source code of tools like [pep8](https://github.com/jcrocholl/pep8/) and [pylint](https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint); this wheel has indeed been invented already, you are just using the wrong tools to build one yourself.

Comment: @thelastblack: Feeding until there is no error is not enough; you'll get the first line of the loop or a function or a class and the first indented line after that, and then the *next* line will throw an exception because it'll be indented too far. And that is because it is really part of the (as yet incomplete) compound statement you just parsed.

Comment: @thelastblack: if you are trying to build a restricted execution environment, parse the whole tree, and run code based on the AST nodes. That's what `asteval` does (linked from the answer).

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to do something like that. I forbid `import`s and I only allow some specific functions and classes. `SyntaxChecker().check(open(sys.argv[1], 'r').read())` did a good job for now, even for cases you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for `asteval`. Seems like a good solution, especially the `symtable` thing

Answer (score 0):

You can parse with is instance(iterator, (Ast,if,Ast.For)) with ast.parse.